# Java changing image color to represent day/night cycle

Tags: java, image, 2d, lighting

I'm currently working on a 2D game in Java and I'm having a little trouble implementing a day/night cycle. I've currently got a system in place that draws a semi-transparent rectangle over the whole screen. Depending on the time in game the rectangle becomes more or less transparent. The problem with this is frame rate takes a huge hit.

So now I'm trying to take the hex color value of the pixel currently being displayed, split it into separate RGB values, and reduce those values then return the number back as a hex in order to draw it to the screen.

This is my code currently. My issue is if the values are greater than 99 the the program crashes.

```
public int getRGB(String hex) {
    if (hex.length() > 1) {
        String temp;
        int colVal;
        temp = hex.substring(2, 4);
        red = Integer.parseInt(temp, 16);
        temp = hex.substring(4, 6);
        green = Integer.parseInt(temp, 16);
        temp = hex.substring(6, 8);
        blue = Integer.parseInt(temp, 16);
        colVal = darkenTile(red, green, blue);
        return colVal;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}

public int darkenTile(int r, int g, int b) {
    int col = 0;
    String red;
    String green;
    String blue;
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        if (r > 0) r--;
        if (g > 0) g--;
        if (b > 0) b--;
    }
    if (r == 0) red = "00";
    else red = Integer.toString(r);
    if (g == 0) green = "00";
    else green = Integer.toString(g);
    if (b == 0) blue = "00";
    else blue = Integer.toString(b);
    String hex = red + green + blue;
    System.out.println(hex);
    col = Integer.parseInt(hex, 16);
    return col;

}
```

When I crash this is what I get.

```
Exception in thread "Display" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "110112129"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
    at com.cousersoft.game.graphics.Screen.darkenTile(Screen.java:178)
    at com.cousersoft.game.graphics.Screen.getRGB(Screen.java:154)
    at com.cousersoft.game.graphics.Screen.renderTile(Screen.java:50)
    at com.cousersoft.game.level.tile.RockTile.render(RockTile.java:13)
    at com.cousersoft.game.level.Level.render(Level.java:84)
    at com.cousersoft.game.Game.render(Game.java:200)
    at com.cousersoft.game.Game.run(Game.java:163)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: which line does the program crash on? what is the error message?

Comment: Reminds me of Castlevania 2: Simon's Quest - "What a horrible night to have a curse."

Comment: you're check whether the `hex` string is more than 1 character long, but you're manipulating it with the assumption that it is 8 characters long e.g. temp = hex.substring(6, 8)

Comment: @Dziugas currently with the call to getRGB the value passed is the color of the current pixel being read from the  map file. The value will always be 0 (a black pixel) or a 6 digit hex value.   The line that is crashing the program is  col = Integer.parseInt(hex, 16); the error I get is Exception in thread "Display" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "110112129"

Comment: Still, can you edit the question to include the stack trace?

Answer (score 0):

The value 110112129 in hex which you're trying to convert to `int` is equal to 4,564,525,353 in decimal - it's larger than the maximum value an integer can store:

`Integer.MAX_VALUE` is 2,147,483,647

The cause of this is because you're converting the r,b,g values to a decimal string instead of a hex string.

Instead of

```
if (r == 0) red = "00";
else red = Integer.toString(r);
if (g == 0) green = "00";
else green = Integer.toString(g);
if (b == 0) blue = "00";
else blue = Integer.toString(b);
```

try:

```
if (r == 0) red = "00";
else red = Integer.toHexString(r);
if (g == 0) green = "00";
else green = Integer.toHexString(g);
if (b == 0) blue = "00";
else blue = Integer.toHexString(b);
```